# Mongoose: How to remove specific array elements from multiple documents?

Tags: mongoose

A Mongodb collection has the following documents:

```
{
  c:"a1",
  ss:[{q:"q1",d:"d1" },{q:"q1",d:"d2" }, {q:"q2",d:"d3" }]
},
{
  c:"a1",
  ss:[{q:"q1",d:"d4" },{q:"q1",d:"d5" }, {q:"q2",d:"d6" }]
},
{
  c:"a2",
  ss:[{q:"q1",d:"d4" },{q:"q1",d:"d5" }, {q:"q2",d:"d6" }]
}
```

I need to match c with value "a1", and remove all array elements in ss, that have q as "q1". I tried the following command, but it did not work. I will greatly appreciate your suggestions. Thanks!

```
update({c:"a1"},{$pullAll:{ss:[{q:"q1"}]}}, {multi:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command actually worked:

```
        update({c:"a1"},{$pull:{ss:{q:"q1"}}}, {multi:true})
```

It seems $pullAll need the array of complete objects. It cannot be array of partial properties in objects.